# SPI voltage level

Tags: raspbian, spi

I had troubles reading an IC (ADAS1000-4) with my raspberry. As soon as I connect the chip to the SPI bus of the Raspberry, the Low voltage doesn't get as low as I expect (please have a look on the photo, where Ch1 is MOSI and Ch2 is CLK; please note, that the "baseline" of Ch1 and Ch2 are shiftet by 3 DIVs).

They both oscilate in an area of 2.0-3.3 volts, which is all a high level.
Do you have an idea how to fix it? Might it help to tie all bus lans to GND using a 10 kOhm resistor?

[image: Please note, that the "baseline" of Ch1 and Ch2 are shiftet by 3 DIVs]

I am using the recent version of raspbian on the Pi 3B+, the software is programmed in C and compiled using gcc

Thanks a lot for you help,
L Fischer

Comment: It is pointless commenting without clear photos showing the connections between the Pi and the chip.

Comment: I would prefer a schematic (there's an editor for that), but first of all, are you confident of your measurements? What's that offset of -3.02V on channel 2? Do you have a ground connection?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev schematics can be useful but I have lost count of the number of times the actual wiring as seen in a photo did not implement the schematic.

Comment: @joan I'd argue that in such cases the schematic by itself is usually also wrong / nonsensical, at which point the OP should be asked to fix it. IMO you have to trust people at some point, and if they post the wrong schematic, or the wrong code, or the wrong config/log file, they're just not going to get a useful answer.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev My experience is we typically get a link to a tutorial containing a schematic along with claims that it has been properly implemented.  Sometimes it has, sometimes it hasn't.

Comment: @joan These should really be closed as unclear IMO, because in my experience 99% of popular tutorials actually do work as advertised, so if the OP claims they implemented the tutorial correclty and it's not working, there's a high chance it's a lie.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev the offset is to have both measurements not on top of each other but being able to see them. The yellow 1 on the left shows where the 0 is for Channel 1, the purple 2 indicates the 0 level of Channel 2. It's just a vertical shifting.

Comment: @joan, I acutally solved it. Somehow I didn't zoom in enough. The oscilloscope displays kind of averaged values, as the single pulse is in a range of approx. 300 ns.